# Xcode5 Push Segue not firing

Tags: ios7, segue, xcode5

I have a simple push segue tied to a button.  When I click on the button in the simulator nothing happens.  Put break points in the prepareforsegue method but the button press doesn't get that far.

Created dozens of push segues but this is the first in Xcode5/iOS7.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your View Controller embedded in a Navigation Controller?

Comment: Solved.  Deleted the segue and added it again via storyboard.  The only thing I did differently was zoom out on the view so the view controllers were smaller.  Weird.